# xml routine not processing the child nodes I want

Tags: java, xml, dom

```
    <report id="oleg">
        <title>olegitimerade rapport</title>
        <id_email>joch1</id_email>
        <id_email>kang15</id_email>
    </report>
```

I am using the following code with the DOM XML parser to extract the above list an xml file.

```
String tag = "report";
String[] elementTags = new String[] {"title", "id_email"};

NodeList nList = this.doc.getElementsByTagName(tag);

    try{
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                HashMap<String, String> attribute = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                if(eElement.hasAttribute("id")){
                    String id = eElement.getAttribute("id");

                    attribute.put("id", id);            

                    for (String elementTag : elementTags){
                        try{

                            int index=0;

                            while(null!=eElement.getElementsByTagName(elementTag).item(index).getTextContent()){
                                attribute.put(elementTag, eElement.getElementsByTagName(elementTag).item(index).getTextContent());
                                index++;
                            }
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            //System.out.println("id : "+id+" - Attribute element '"+ elementTag+ "' not found in XML! ["+this.xmlFile+"]");
                        }   
                    }

                    attributes.add(attribute);
                }
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The problem is when I get the multiple  tags....I cannot extract the 2nd ID (kang15).

Clearly the while loop is incorrect, so I need a little help here fixing the issue.

```
   while(null!=eElement.getElementsByTagName(elementTag).item(index).getTextContent()){
                            attribute.put(elementTag, eElement.getElementsByTagName(elementTag).item(index).getTextContent());
                            index++;
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [XPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) for this:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory
    .newInstance()
    .newXPath();
Element report = (Element) xpath.evaluate("//report", doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
String id = xpath.evaluate("@id", report);
String title = xpath.evaluate("title", report);
NodeList emails = (NodeList)
              xpath.evaluate("id_email/text()", report, XPathConstants.NODESET);

System.out.println(id);
System.out.println(title);
for(int i=0; i<emails.getLength(); i++) {
  System.out.println(emails.item(i).getTextContent());
}
```